# Git hub Organization

Tags: github, github-organizations

I have a problem in creating a git organization. The problem is, I already created a Git organization, but then a deleted it. When I tried to create an organization with the same name. It says its unavailable.

Comment: Why not ask their customer support about this? I would assume they know best how their system works

Comment: already tried that but no reply yet.

Answer (score 0):

Citation from [Github Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-organization-settings/deleting-an-organization-account):

> When you delete an organization, all repositories, forks of private
> repositories, wikis, issues, pull requests, and Project or
> Organization Pages are deleted as well. Your billing will end, **and
> after 90 days the organization name becomes available for use on a new
> user or organization account.**

I guess, you should wait for 90 days, or try another name.

Comment: Ill have to go with the latter. thanks man.